Ramsey fringe question (no oscillation at zero detuning)
I think I understand the Ramsey fringe using the Bloch sphere picture, but I am still confused about the 2D plots where we we vary both free evolution time and drive frequency.
I was looking at this plot from this website.
I noticed that when the drive frequency is on resonance with the qubit, there is no oscillation (where the detuning in the plot is zero).
Is this because when Ramsey experiment is performed, we work in the rotating frame set by the drive frequency? Hence, when the drive frequency is on resonance with the qubit frequency, applying $ \pi/2 $ pulse twice with free evolution $\tau$ inbetween does not result in a damped sinusoidal oscillation? Assuming no decay and no dephasing, it would be the same as applying a single $\pi$ pulse and hence, no oscillation observed at zero detuning frequency (in the plot linked).
I wanted to confirm that I have the right picture.
